# How to efficiently apply a function to every row in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, string, performance

Given the following table:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'code':['100M','60M10N40M','5S99M','1S25I100M','1D1S1I200M']})
```

that looks like this:

```
    code
0   100M
1   60M10N40M
2   5S99M
3   1S25I100M
4   1D1S1I200M
```

I'd like to convert the `code` column strings to numbers where M, N, D are each equivalent to (times 1), I is equivalent to (times -1) and S is equivalent to (times 0).

The result should look like this:

```
     code       Val
0   100M        100     This is (100*1)
1   60M10N40M   110     This is (60*1)+(10*1)+(40*1)
2   5S99M       99      This is (5*0)+(99*1)
3   1S25I100M   75      This is (1*0)+(25*-1)+(100*1)
4   1D1S1I200M  200     This is (1*1)+(1*0)+(1*-1)+(200*1)
```

I wrote the following function to this:

```py
def String2Val(String):
    # Generate substrings
    sstrings = re.findall('.[^A-Z]*.', String)

    KeyDict = {'M':'*1','N':'*1','I':'*-1','S':'*0','D':'*1'}

    newlist = []
    for key, value in KeyDict.items():
        for i in sstrings:
            if key in i:
                p = i.replace(key, value)
                lp = eval(p)
                newlist.append(lp)

    OutputVal = sum(newlist)
    return OutputVal

df['Val'] = df.apply(lambda row: String2Val(row['code']), axis = 1)
```

After applying this function to the table, I realized it's not efficient and takes forever when applied to large datasets. How can I optimize this process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since pandas string methods are not optimized (although that seems to no longer be true for pandas 2.0), if you're after performance, it's better to use Python string methods in a loop (which are compiled in C). It seems a straightforward loop over each string might give the best performance.

```py
def evaluater(s):
    total, curr = 0, ''
    for e in s:
        # if a number concatenate to the previous number
        if e.isdigit():
            curr += e
        # if a string, look up its value in KeyDict
        # and multiply the currently collected number by it
        # and add to the total
        else:
            total += int(curr) * KeyDict[e]
            curr = ''
    return total

KeyDict = {'M': 1, 'N': 1, 'I': -1, 'S': 0, 'D': 1}
df['val'] = df['code'].map(evaluater)
```

Performance:

```py
KeyDict1 = {'M':'*1+','N':'*1+','I':'*-1+','S':'*0+','D':'*1+'}
df = pd.DataFrame({'code':['100M','60M10N40M','5S99M','1S25I100M','1D1S1I200M']*1000})

%timeit df.assign(val=df['code'].map(evaluater))
# 12.2 ms ± 579 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit df.assign(val=df['code'].apply(String2Val))    # @Marcelo Paco
# 61.8 ms ± 2.47 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit df.assign(val=df['code'].replace(KeyDict1, regex=True).str.rstrip('+').apply(pd.eval))   # @Ynjxsjmh
# 4.86 s ± 155 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

N.B. You already implement something similar but the outer loop (`for key, value in KeyDict.items()`) is unnecessary; since `KeyDict` is a dictionary, use it as a lookup table; don't loop. Also, `.apply(axis=1)` is a really bad way to loop when only a single column is relevant. Select that column and call `apply()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the addition symbol to the value of `KeyDict` then replace the value of `code` column by the `KeyDict` and at last call `pd.eval` to do the calculation.

```py
KeyDict = {'M':'*1+','N':'*1+','I':'*-1+','S':'*0+','D':'*1+'}


df['val'] = (df['code'].replace(KeyDict, regex=True)
             .str.rstrip('+').apply(pd.eval))
# or you can use native python for loop since Series.apply is not efficient
df['val'] = [pd.eval(val) for val in df['code'].replace(KeyDict, regex=True).str.rstrip('+')]
```

```
print(df)

         code  val
0        100M  100
1   60M10N40M  110
2       5S99M   99
3   1S25I100M   75
4  1D1S1I200M  200
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to help with this. I tested by scaling up the df by a factor of 10000. It took 1:33s to run the first solution, the second solution took 1:34s. The function I showed took 4.06s. I'm hoping for much faster results given an even larger scale. The alternates above are indeed efficient with fewer lines, I was more leaning towards performance.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following solution that uses `replace()`:

```
import pandas as pd

def String2Val(row):
    # Use replace to find an replace characters according to your KeyDict definition
    val = row.replace('M', '*1+').replace('N', '*1+').replace('I', '*-1+').replace('S', '*0+').replace('D', '*1+')
    # Ensure the last part of the string isn't a +
    if val[-1] == "+":
        # If it is, remove the + from the end
        val = val[:-1]
    # Return the evaluated value
    return eval(val)

df = pd.DataFrame({'code':['100M','60M10N40M','5S99M','1S25I100M','1D1S1I200M']})
# Modify it to use apply only on the code column. Which removes the need to use lambda and axis=1
df['Val'] = df['code'].apply(String2Val)
```

`df`:

```
         code  Val
0        100M  100
1   60M10N40M  110
2       5S99M   99
3   1S25I100M   75
4  1D1S1I200M  200
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, which replaces the letters by the corresponding multiplicative factor and, then, evaluates the strings with `eval`:

```
df['val'] = (df['code'].str.replace('M|N|D', '*1+', regex=True)
             .str.replace('I', '*(-1)+', regex=True)
             .str.replace('S', '*0+', regex=True)
             .str.replace(r'\+$', '', regex=True).map(eval))
```

Output:

```
         code  val
0        100M  100
1   60M10N40M  110
2       5S99M   99
3   1S25I100M   75
4  1D1S1I200M  200
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all. In case this may be helpful to others, I checked the performance of everyone's solution on data of different sizes and obtained the following results. Very educational, great tips to be applied when working with large datasets.

[image]